# Rate Limits, Facebook Graph API and Javascript

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

My search didn't come up with a relevant answer for my problem so I post here hoping to get guidance.

I am developing a not-for-profit website for finding assisted-living solutions.
Each web page has social buttons for sharing/liking in Facebook and it shows the number of shares/likes. We do not require logging for viewing pages.

The problem is that we are constantly hitting the rate limits because of the API calls to get the number of likes (which is important to present) and then the Facebook buttons do not show.

this problem is several months old, probably the limits were changed, or maybe permissions?

All calls are done with the app id.
This is the js that is used when a page loads:

```
//<!--Start Facebook Script-->
     window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
         FB.init({
             appId: 'my-app-id',
             xfbml: true,
             version: 'v3.1'
         });
     };

(function (d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id))  return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/he_IL/sdk.js';
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And the markup for the Facebook buttons is also standard - as suggested by Facebook.

```
  <div style="padding:5px 0; display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
                <div class="fb-like" data-layout="button_count" data-href="the-webpage-url" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true" style="display:inline-block;"></div>
  </div>
```

Here are solutions that we have seen but do not wish to use:

- We do not want to cache social information
- We do not wish to force users to login in order to view the number of likes etc. (Of course they do have to log if they want to actively share or like).

I hope someone can suggest a solution.

Thanks

Comment: You note that you do not want to cache social information. By this, I assume that you also do not want to cache the information for a single 'visit' to your website? I assume you are currently sending an API call every time a user clicks on a webpage, but if you do it once when they first visit and then store that information for say, 5 minutes, then you may not need to send extra API calls for remainder of that user's visit.

Comment: things like that are the reason why there are limits, and why they are kept small. you need to cache results, never call the api for every single user. where is the code with the api call? that´s the important part. hopefully, you are not using a hardcoded access token in client code?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. @luschn I have edited the answer with the markup, which is standard, I think.

Comment: If you only embed the social plugins, then that should not count against the rate limits to begin with, AFAIK. Are you sure those are causing the problem in the first place?

Comment: yeah, if THAT is really hitting a limit, you should open a bug. "because of the API calls to get the number of likes" suggests that you are doing an api call on your own though?

Comment: Thanks. I will open a bug report.